# Sessions and concurrency and how they are related

Tags: puppeteer, apify

I'm building a PuppeteerCrawler and I have to login to a certain website. But the website doesn't allow for multiple browsers to be using the same account at the same time. From my understanding, the session is persisted to a single IP, but how can i make that session also be exclusive to an browser instance?

I'm also using 10 input users to be rotated by the following function.

```
exports.authenticate = async (page) => {
    const  { users }  = await Apify.getInput();
    const user = Math.round(Math.random() * 10 ); 

    let isLogged = await loggedCheck(page);

    if (!isLogged) {
        log.debug(`Cookies from cache didn't work, trying to login..`);
        await page.type('input[name="email"]', users[user].username);
        await page.type('input[name="password"]', users[user].password);
        await page.click('input[name="submit"]');
        isLogged = await loggedCheck(page);
    }

    if (!isLogged) {
        throw new Error('Didn\'t work!');        
    }
};
```

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/85

Comment: Thanks, it was good help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, session IPs are exclusive to a browser instance and in `PuppeteerCrawler` they can be managed using the `SessionPool`

Check this out, should be helpful: https://sdk.apify.com/docs/guides/session-management